# Поведение объектов с position: absolute при изменении размеров окна

Tags: html, css, position

Добрый день!

```css
 .black {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .red {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="black">
        <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
```

При изменении размеров окна (или переходе с пк на смартфон) красный блок начинает двигаться относительно черного. Есть ли возможность этого избежать, при этом сохранив position: absolute для блока .red? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Отцу прописать `position:relative`. то есть черному блоку.

```css
 .black {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .red {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="black">
        <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет, он всё время двигается относительно body. Из-за пропорций создается впечатление, что движение происходит относительно блока .black.

Comment: Большое спасибо!